# I want to update fields (X,Y) in table A to the values in fields (X,Y) in table B, where the fields Z are equal in both

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
    a_fees a
    a_temp b
SET
    b.fee_source_id = a.fee_source, 
    b.filing_date = a.filingdate
WHERE
    b.fee_id = a.fee_id;
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL syntax for a multiple table update:

```
UPDATE a_fees AS a, a_temp AS b
SET a.fee_source = b.fee_source_id, 
    a.filingdate = b.filing_date
WHERE a.fee_id = b.fee_id;
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2adc/1)

Using an `INNER JOIN`:

```
UPDATE a_fees AS a
INNER JOIN a_temp AS b
ON a.fee_id = b.fee_id
SET a.fee_source = b.fee_source_id, 
    a.filingdate = b.filing_date;
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c03afb/1)

Comment: @BenJones: It means the same thing and will have the same performance. I've updated my answer to show both methods using the MySQL syntax.

Comment: @BenJones: Yes, it most definitely matters! The left side of the assignment is overwritten with the value from the right side. If you put it the wrong way round it will overwrite all your good values with the bad ones instead of the other way around! I hope you have a backup...

Comment: But just as a side note - I got the tables backwards. I wanted to update a_fees and drop a_temp once the update was done.. so I think I can work that out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `UPDATE` statement to update fields in a table. If you were in SQL Server, you would update the fields in one table with the values from a different table using JOINs as follows:

```
UPDATE b
SET
    b.fee_source_id = a.fee_source, 
    b.filing_date = a.filingdate
FROM 
    a_fees a
    JOIN a_temp b
    ON a.fee_id = b.fee_id
```

Comment: I understand you are not familiar with the actual tables, but I was trying update the a_fees table from the data contained in the a_temp table. So does it matter which order I have the fields in the SET clause?

Comment: Yes, it does. The one on the LHS should be set with values from the column on the RHS. I saw in your query that you were setting the values in a_temp from those in a_fees, which was contradicting with the title of the question.

Comment: OK Excellent. Yes I got the title of the question wrong. What you have written is what I am looking at doing, except just switch the tables around. Thank you @Vikdor

Answer (score 0):

The only syntax that I know that works across databases is:

```
update a_temp
    set fee_source_id = (select a_fees.fee_source from a_fees f where a_temp.fee_id = af.fee_id),
        filing_date = (select a_fees.filing_date from a_fees f where a_temp.fee_id = af.fee_id)
    where a_temp.fee_id in (select fee_id from a_fees)
```

Really ugly syntax, using two correlated subqueries (the `where` clause is to handle cases with non-matching fee_ids), which is why most databases have a mechanism that supports joins in `update` queries.